# Getting a date to pull from a parent to a response on creation

Tags: javascript, xpages

So given this code for pre loading fields from a parent record to a new response record.  I can get the ParentUNID and the HolderName values to load no problem, but I am missing something on passing the date values?

```
<xp:this.beforePageLoad><![CDATA[#{javascript:  
var parentDoc = database.getDocumentByUNID(document1.getParentId());
document1.setValue("ParentUNID", parentDoc.getItemValue("DocID"));
document1.setValue("Policy_HolderName", parentDoc.getItemValue("Policy_HolderName"));
document1.setValue("Policy_Eff_Date", parentDoc.getItemValue("Policy_Eff_Date"));}]]></xp:this.beforePageLoad>
```

Comment: What happens? Does it throw an error? Does it return an empty value? Does it return a wrong value?

Comment: yes just a empty value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Copy](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_9.0.1/reference/r_domino_Document_copyItem.html) the *item* itself and not just item's *value*. This way you copy all item's properties too:

```
...
document1.getDocument().copyItem(parentDoc.getFirstItem("Policy_Eff_Date"));
...
```

Comment: So, I have some basic confusion.  You can see parentDoc being set document1 is set as a xp:this.data dominoDocument.  

So I can use the copyItem on parentDoc, but the type for document1 doesn't allow that as an option?  I am missing something obvious.

Comment: You're right. I updated my answer: first we need to get document1's backend-document and then we can copy the item.

Comment: We have a winner.  Don't know why I was missing that. 

Thanks